# Selecting Channel data within a custom Addon

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development

I'm going to be inserting some data into a channel via a custom Add-on. It looks as thought I should be using the [Channel Entries API](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html) in order to do this, which is fine.

What I need to do first though is select some supporting data from some existing Channels. There doesn't seem to be anything in the above API to fetch existing data unless I missed it. What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm happy to use the [DB Class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html), if that's the only way of doing it. I just wanted to check there wasn't a preferred method of doing this before I go re-inventing the wheel!

Any help, gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that fetching data from existing channels/entries is just a case of querying the database so it's either straight to the [DB class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html) or via [CI Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) It's probably better to use the Active Record class.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Looks like I was headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You should look here: https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data

It might help you.

Comment: Yup, I was going to post the same thing. I wrote Channel Data for this exact purpose. It uses the DB class and active record so it's really a step beyond that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this looks like it'll do the trick nicely.

Comment: Hey, nice. I wasn't aware of Channel Date but that looks like a time saver. Do you know of any existing extensions which use this Class so I can take a look at and break down a real-world example?

Comment: I'd be grateful of some examples as well, as I'm struggling to get to grips with it.

Comment: Ok, I check the repository of the Channel-Data. But there was no info of how to install it. Where to put these files?